# equivalent conditions for orthogonal transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

An operator on a complex vector space is normal $\iff$ $||Tx||=||T^*x||$ for all $x$. $\implies$ is true over real vector spaces as well, but for the direction $\Longleftarrow$ is this also true over real vector spaces? I ask because the proof I know for this direction with complex vector spaces uses the fact that $\langle Tx,x\rangle=0$ for all $x\implies T=0$, but this is only true in complex vector spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is valid, and the proof is irrelevant to the base field.

By defintion, $\mathcal T$ is normal $\iff \mathcal {TT}^* = \mathcal T^* \mathcal T$. Therfore, 
\begin{align*}
&\quad \mathcal T^*\mathcal T = \mathcal {TT}^* \\
&\iff (\mathcal T^*\mathcal T - \mathcal {TT}^*) v = 0 \: [\forall v \in V]\\
&\iff ((\mathcal T^*\mathcal T - \mathcal {TT}^*)v|v) = 0 \\
&\iff (\mathcal T^*\mathcal Tv|v)=( \mathcal{TT}^*v|v) \\
&\iff (\mathcal Tv|\mathcal Tv) = (\mathcal T^*v|\mathcal T^*v) \\
&\iff \lVert \mathcal Tv \rVert^2 = \lVert \mathcal T^*v \rVert^2.
\end{align*}

Comment: Is this right? I'm not sure about the second $\iff$. $T=0\implies (Tv,v)=0$, but $(Tv,v)=0$ for all $v$ $\implies T=0$ is only true over $C$?

Comment: Oh, wait, $T^*T-TT^*$ is self-adjoint. Never mind :)

Comment: @user153582 Well, this equivalence is irrelevant to the self-adjoint property in this problem. It is simply the definition of zero operator.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $||Tx||=||T^{*}x||$ for all x. Consider $<TT^{*}x,y>=<T^{*}x,T^{*}y>$. Also $<T^{*}Tx,y>=<Tx,Ty>$. Given that the linear map $T \to T^{*}$ preserves norms we have to show that it preserves inner products. This follows from the following formula for inner product in terms of norm: $<x,y>= \frac {||x+y||^{2}+||x-y||^{2}} 4$.

Comment: Sorry, I typed + in place of - on the right side of the identity.